# Get Label or value of DropdownItem to set text value to DropdownToggle

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im trying to get the value of DropdownItem  in a DropDownMenu to set the value (or label name) in the DropDownToggle tag, instead of a static text that says: "Dropdown"  I want the active option innerText to be displayed. (what a redundant post....)

But yes... the issue is that I'm not sure how to get the options label or value. I saw that  for react native has a property that do that but Im using React.js.

I tried many solutions and one that "worked" (kind of) was to create an object with the velues but I dont know how to bind them to the options with hooks or similar, like this:

```
const options = [
  { value: '', label: 'All' },
  { value: 'favorite', label: 'Favorite' },
  { value: 'recent', label: 'Recent' }
];
```

and then render it with:

```
return(
  <Select className="mt-4 col-md-8 col-offset-4"
  options = { options }
/>
);
```

But again... Im not getting the idea how to bind them to my actual code... So I came with the questions... how do I get the innerText of the option that I want to be displayed when the option is active? should I save it in a state? or is there an easier way to do it?

This is my code so you can see what I mean...:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Col,
  Container,
  ListGroup,
  ListGroupItem,
  Nav,
  Row,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
 import {Favorite} from './Favorite';

export const ByCourse = ({projects, updateProjects}) => {
  console.log('window.projects = ', projects);

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(); <-------- Here I declared my filters

  const filteredProjects = !filter ? projects : projects.filter(project => project[filter]);

  return (
    <div className="section-component">
      <h2 className="mt-2 mb-4">By Course</h2>

  <Nav className="nav-tabs mb-3">
    <UncontrolledDropdown setActiveFromChild>
      <DropdownToggle tag="button" className="nav-link" caret>

        Filter: {filter}   <---------- Here I want to display the label names of the options

      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem tag="button" onClick={() => setFilter()} active>

          All <--------------- this should be displayed when it is active or by default, now it display only the value of my function for filtering.

        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem tag="button" onClick={() => setFilter('favorite')}>

          Favorite <----------------- this should be displayes when active

        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem tag="button" onClick={() => setFilter('recent')}>

          Recent  <----------------- this should be displayes when active

        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem tag="button" onClick={() => setFilter('userAssigned')}>

          User Assigned <----------------- this should be displayes when active

        </DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  </Nav>

  <Container className={'p-0'}>
    {filteredProjects.map(project => {
      return (
        <Row key={project.projectId} className={'h-100'}>
          <Col md={12} className={'p-0'}>
            <ListGroup> ........
```

I really apreciate any help or guidence with this reactstrap component and my facepalm issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the solution to my problem, it wasnt very far away from the aproch I took first. So here is a working code for getting (in this case) text of dropdown menu.

```
const items = [
  {label: 'All', filter: project => true},
  {label: 'Favorite', filter: project => project.favorite},
  {label: 'Recent', filter: project => project.recent},
  {label: 'User Assigned', filter: project => project.userAssigned},
];

export const ByCourse = ({projects, updateProjects}) => {
  console.log('window.projects = ', projects);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(items[0]);
  const filteredProjects = !filter ? projects : projects.filter(project => 
filter.filter(project));

return (
<div className="section-component">
  <h1 className="mt-2 mb-4">By Course</h1>
  <Nav className="nav-tabs mb-3">
    <UncontrolledDropdown setActiveFromChild>
      <DropdownToggle tag="button" className="nav-link pl-0" style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}  caret>
        Filter: {filter.label}
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <DropdownItem key={index} tag="button" onClick={() => setFilter(item)} active>
            {item.label}
          </DropdownItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  </Nav>
```